# Simplify lots of SED command

Tags: bash, sed

I have the following command that I use to rewrite some maxscale output to be able to use it in other software:

```
maxadmin list servers | sed -r 's/[^a-z 0-9]//gi;/^\s*$/d;1,3d;' | awk '$1=$1' | cut -d ' ' -f 1,5 | sed -e 's/ /":"/g' | sed -e 's/\(.*\)/"\1"/' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's/.$/}\n/' | sed 's/^/{/'
```

I am thinking this is way to complex for what I want to do, but I am not able to see a simpler version of this myself. What I want is to rewrite this (output of *maxadmin list servers*):

```
Servers.
-------------------+-----------------+-------+-------------+--------------------
Server             | Address         | Port  | Connections | Status
-------------------+-----------------+-------+-------------+--------------------
svr_node1          | 192.168.178.1 |  3306 |           0 | Master, Synced, Running
svr_node2          | 192.168.178.1 |  3306 |           0 | Slave, Synced, Running
svr_node3          | 192.168.178.1 |  3306 |           0 | Slave, Synced, Running
-------------------+-----------------+-------+-------------+--------------------
```

Into this:

```
{"svrnode1":"Master","svrnode2":"Slave","svrnode3":"Slave"}
```

My command does a good job but as I said, there should be a simpler way with less sed commands being run hopefully.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking to review *working* code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: I wonder for what `awk '$1=$1'` is meant for in the question. Please cleanup your code before you post it here. At least as best as you can.

Comment: "working" is quite relative in this case, but sure. My question has been answered though, so I am happy.

And to answer the code cleanup. This really was the best I could do, unfortunately. If I remove that it doesn't work, so yeah.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `awk`, like  this:

*json.awk*

```
BEGIN {
    printf "{" 
}
# Everything after line for and before the last ------ line
# plus the last empty line (if any).
NR>4&&!/^([-]|$)/{
    sub(/,/,"",$9) # Remove trailing comma
    printf "%s\"%s\":\"%s\"",s,$1,$9
    s="," # Set comma separator after first iteration
}
END {
    print "}" 
}
```

Run it like this:

```
maxadmin list servers | awk -f json.awk
```

Output:

```
{"svr_node1":"Master","svr_node2":"Slave","svr_node3":"Slave"}
```

---

In comments there came up the question how to achieve that without an extra `json.awk` file:

```
maxadmin list servers | awk 'BEGIN{printf"{"}NR>4&&!/^([-]|$)/{sub(/,/,"",$9);printf"%s\"%s\":\"%s\"",s,$1,$9;s=","}END{print"}"}'
```

Ugly, but works. ;)

If you want to put this into a shell script, consider a multiline version like this:

```
maxadmin list servers | awk '
    BEGIN{printf"{"}
    NR>4&&!/^([-]|$)/{
        sub(/,/,"",$9)
        printf"%s\"%s\":\"%s\"",s,$1,$9
        s=","
    }
    END{print"}"}'
```

Comment: That is indeed a great solution, but I should have clarified that I have the need to execute this in a single line without additional files (hence the horrible piping of multiple sed commands).

Comment: I've added a version without an extra `json.awk`

Comment: Glad that it helped you